# $F$-subalgebra is closed under taking inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be finite dimensional and $\mathcal{A} \subset \operatorname{End}_F(V)$ be an $F$-subalgebra, that is, a subspace containing the identity map and closed under multiplication. Suppose that $T \in \mathcal{A}$ is invertible in $\operatorname{End}_F(V)$.

How to show that the inverse of $T$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ as well?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $T$ as an element of $\text{End}_F(V)$.
Its constant term is nonzero, so
$$T^n+a_aT^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0I=0$$
for some $a_j\in F$ with $a_0\ne0$. One can rearrange this as $Tg(T)=I$
where $g$ is a polynomial over $F$. Therefore $T^{-1}=g(T)\in\cal{A}$.